# Open balls form a base of the topology on R (reals)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In a real analysis course and the professor has just given us an assignment that first introduces topology and metric spaces. Here is the question:

Def: Given $x$ $\in \Bbb{R}$ , let $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ denote the set of all real numbers $z$ with $|x-z|<\epsilon$ .

Prove that whenever $z$ $\in A$ $=$ $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap B_{\delta}(y)$ , there exists $\rho > 0$ with $B_{\rho}(z) \subset A$ .

As an additional note, he writes that this relates to how open balls form a base for the topology on $\Bbb{R}$. Currently in the course we have talked about $\epsilon - \delta$ continuity of functions, but I have no clue how I would go about proving this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think that drawing a picture would help you significantly to start understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

$\rho=\min(\epsilon-|z-x|\ ,\ \delta-|y-z|)$

And use the triangular inequality to prove what you need.

Again like B. Pasternak said it is crucial that you draw a picture. It helps alot.